# How to solve the problem of same OSM ID of different Lat, Long pairs?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, postgresql-9.3, pgrouting

(I am not a native English speaker so please ignore my grammar mistakes.)

I have a PostgreSQL database name as Karachi and I have downloaded osm karachi map from **https://download.bbbike.org/** in shp file format then I converted it to GeoJSON using QGIS and then imported this Karachi.geojson to PostgreSQL through these commands:

```
ogr2ogr -select name -nlt CONVERT_TO_LINEAR -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=the_geom -lco FID=id -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname='Karachi' host='localhost' port='5432' user='postgres' password='Password'" -nln edges Karachi.geojson -where "OGR_GEOMETRY='MultiLineString'"

ALTER TABLE edges ADD source INT4;
ALTER TABLE edges ADD target INT4;
ALTER TABLE edges ALTER COLUMN the_geom TYPE geometry(linestring,4326) USING ST_GeometryN(the_geom, 1);

SELECT pgr_nodeNetwork('edges', 0.00001);
SELECT pgr_createTopology('edges_noded', 0.00001);

ALTER TABLE edges_noded ADD COLUMN name VARCHAR,ADD COLUMN type VARCHAR;

UPDATE edges_noded AS new SET name=old.name FROM edges as old WHERE new.old_id=old.id;

ALTER TABLE edges_noded ADD distance FLOAT8;

UPDATE edges_noded SET distance = ST_Length(ST_Transform(the_geom, 4326)::geography) / 1000;
```

After that I have two latitudes and longitudes

1. `67.112457,24.882638`
2. `67.113009,24.882293`

I want to find distance between these two latitude and longitude so I use this query for getting osm ids:

```
SELECT v.id, v.the_geom, string_agg(distinct(e.name),',') AS name
FROM edges_noded_vertices_pgr AS v, edges_noded AS e
WHERE v.id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM edges_noded_vertices_pgr
    ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(67.0691865,24.9065008), 4326)
    LIMIT 1
  )
  AND (e.source = v.id OR e.target = v.id)
GROUP BY v.id, v.the_geom
```

This query returns me same osm id for both (lat,long)s
How to solve this problem?

Is there any other solution to this problem by using windows 10?